# How to access XML element array under an XML element?

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file which I read and deserialize into an object "newProject" using XMLSerializer. I need to modify certain parts of the object and serialize back into an XML file.

I can do this for the most part, but cannot figure out how to change values if there is an array of XML element under an XML element.

For example I have the following class:

```cs
public partial class addDataData {

    private System.Xml.XmlElement anyField;

    private string nameField;

    private addDataDataHandleUnknown handleUnknownField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()]
    public System.Xml.XmlElement Any {
        get {
            return this.anyField;
        }
        set {
            this.anyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write values to the xml array elements under the "Any" element.

I've tried:

```
newProject.addData[i].Any[0] = fbFolderList[0];
```

I get Error "Argument 1: Cannot conver from int to string" because VS wants you to type in the XML string name here.

I also tried:

```
newProject.addData[i].Any = fbFolderList.ToArray();
```

Where the fbFolderList contains XML elements that I modified.
This also give me error

```
Cannot implicityly convert System.xml.xmlElement[] to system.xml.xmlElement
```

[VS wants me to insert a XmlNode name in the [] to get the xml element instead of referencing the array element number...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vd6FL.png)

Here is a screen shot of the object structure.

When I try using a `foreach` loop I can access the array values under "Any" element, but as you know, you cannot write values into the foreach iteration variable.

```cs
private void ReadAddData(addDataData[] data)
{
    foreach (addDataData d in data)
    {
        foreach(XmlElement folder in d.Any)
        {
              fbFolderList.Add(folder)
        }
    }   
}
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler or the program that I want to access the array values and not to get the xml element name?

Thank you I appreciate any help you can give me.

Sorry I'm new and not sure how I can attach an Xml file to this post. The Xml is huge, but I've attaches a screenshot of the xml in watch window
[xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF03W.png)

Here is the simplified form of my xml document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.plcopen.org/xml/tc6_0201">
  <fileHeader companyName="x" companyURL="xx"/>
  <instances>
    <configurations></configurations>
  </instances>
  <addData>
    <data name="http:/xml/projectPlcType" handleUnknown="implementation">
      <projectPlcType name="R08" />
    </data>
    <data name="http:/xml/projectFolders" handleUnknown="implementation">
      <projectFolders>
        <folder name="AVM" type="functionBlock" functionBlockType="macro" modificationDateTime="2018-11-08T12:08:01-06:00" />
        <folder name="PLCOpenServo" type="functionBlock" functionBlockType="macro" modificationDateTime="2018-11-12T10:09:16-06:00" />
      </projectFolders>
    </data>
  </addData>
</project>
```

Comment: Just add the new properties like all the other current properties you are reading.  The read doesn't care if the new items are missing from the existing xml.

Comment: To clarify, I can access properties under the "Any" element like: ".....Any.Attributes" or "Any.Value". I want to be able to access an array element under the Any element like: "Any[0].Attribute". I know that the array exists because I can see it in the watch window and I can foreach loop through it, but it won't let me type in a the element number in between the  brackets [ ].

Comment: Why you use XElement Array you will get two levels of tags Name and Names (names contains the array).  Sometimes you need to use [XElement] which will give one class just Names (with the array).

Comment: Can you share an example of the XML you are currently deserializing to `addDataData`, and the XML you are trying to create?  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: `Any` is not an array by the way.  It's a single item.  An array would look like `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAnyElementAttribute()] public System.Xml.XmlElement[] Any { get; set; }`.  (Notice the extra brackets.)

Comment: Than you for your comments, I realize it would be hard without the xml, so I attached a screenshot at the end. Not sure how I can add xml file to the post.

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your XML as **text** rather than as a screenshot?  It's required here not to to use images for this textual data, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186) may also help.  If the full XML doesn't fit, trim it down to a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: dbc, sorry about the newbie mistakes. I completely agree with your comments and thank I appreciate you pointing it out to me with links I can follow. I simplified the xml and attached it to the post.